# context.startService crashing on Oreo

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I have an android app that takes location data every 30 minutes. Here's how I have registered the broadcast receiver.

```
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("com.example.partners.alarms");
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            time.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 30, alarmIntent);
```

and then it gets called like this:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, AttendanceChecker.class));
    ((OperationsApplication)context.getApplicationContext()).getJobManager().start();
}

}
```

This has been working fine so far, but with Android O its crashing. I read online regarding this but couldn't come up with the right solution.

EDIT:
The startService() method throws an IllegalStateException

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3303)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1746)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:192)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6688)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:445)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:867)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1526)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1482)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:650)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:650)
  at com.example.app.AlarmReceiver.onReceive (AlarmReceiver.java:11)
```

Comment: *`context.startService crashing on Android O`* where is your Crash log?

Comment: added in edit. @NileshRathod

Answer (score 3):

Android 8.0 (API level 26) also includes the following changes to specific methods:

The startService() method now throws an IllegalStateException if an app targeting Android 8.0 tries to use that method in a situation when it isn't permitted to create background services.

The new `Context.startForegroundService()` method starts a foreground service. The system allows apps to call `Context.startForegroundService()` even while the app is in the background. However, the app must call that service's startForeground() method within five seconds after the service is created.  Read this , it will help you 
         https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes